# how can I have custom two way databinding make a form dirty

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

I created a component with two way databinding

```
class MyCustom2Way{
      @Input() text: string;
      @Output() textChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
      // MyCustom2Way has something in the template that will 
      // trigger testChange.emit when user interacts with it
}
```

Now suppose I use `MyCustom2Way` in a form like this :

```
<form action="" #myForm="ngForm">
  <my-custom-2-way [(text)]="model.field" name="field"></my-custom-2-way>
</form>
```

How can I have `MyCustom2Way` turn `myForm` dirty when user iteracts with `MyCustom2Way` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ngModel` and custom `ControlValueAccessor`, otherwise form does not know anything about your component, so it will not be marked as dirty. `[(text)]="model.field"` - is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the form to my-custom-2-way component like this

```
<my-custom-2-way [(text)]="model.field" name="field" [form]="myForm"></my-custom-2-way>
```

then in my custom component

```
class MyCustom2Way{
      @Input() text: string;
      @Output() textChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
      // MyCustom2Way has something in the template that will 
      // trigger testChange.emit when user interacts with it
      @Input Form:any 
      this.form._pristine=true;
}
```